# how to find out how many 'name' are in a list

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I create a bot for telegram and ran into the problem of counting the number of values to display the Inline keyboard. I have a list and data that can change and I need to bring in the keyboard all `names` and `addresses` in the Inline, only I would like this keyboard to adjust to the number of values (I know how to create Inline-buttons that show all names and addresses. But I am necessary that each button has its own callback)

```
text=[{'id': 'fd65865b-0f43-468b-80a5-04d5c9f90086', 'vendorId': '232231', 'name': 'магазин-кафетерій', 'location': {'settlement': 'Київ', 'addressLine': 'м.Київ вул.А.Ахматової 35'}, 'freeVisit': False}, {'id': '2a2d898c-853c-453b-a8c3-0acd0e1ebc8a', 'vendorId': '232830', 'name': 'магазин', 'location': {'settlement': 'Київ', 'addressLine': 'м.Київ вул.Радунська,13-А'}, 'freeVisit': False}.....]

selectKeyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup( row_width=1)
lenname=[i.split("name")[0] for i in text]
    print(lenname)

if 0<lenname<2:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        one=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[0]['name']),callback_data="first")

    selectKeyboard.add(one)

if 1<lenname<3:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        one=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[0]['name'])+"  ",callback_data="first")
        two=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[1]['name'])+"  ",callback_data="second")

    selectKeyboard.add(one,two)

if 2<lenname<4:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        one=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[0]['name'])+"  ",callback_data="first")
        two=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[1]['name'])+"  ",callback_data="second")
        three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[2]['name']) + "  " ,callback_data="three")

    selectKeyboard.add(one,two,three)


And ....
```

I expect the output of dynamic keyboard, but the actual output is 1 Inline button

Comment: This code should raise an AttributeError in line 4.

Answer (score 0):

I understood how to do it. I sumed all `i`

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    name = text[i]['name']
    vendor = text[i]['vendorId']
    address=text[i]['location']['addressLine']
    pprint(name)

    sumaI+=i

print(sumaI)


selectKeyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup( row_width=1)

if sumaI==0:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        one=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[0]['name'])+"  "+str(text[0]['location']['addressLine']),callback_data="first")

    selectKeyboard.add(one)

elif  sumaI==1:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        one=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[0]['name'])+"  "+str(text[0]['location']['addressLine']),callback_data="first")
        two=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[1]['name'])+"  "+str(text[1]['location']['addressLine']),callback_data="second")

    selectKeyboard.add(one,two)

elif sumaI==3:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        one=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[0]['name'])+"  "+str(text[0]['location']['addressLine']),callback_data="first")
        two=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[1]['name'])+"  "+str(text[1]['location']['addressLine']),callback_data="second")
        three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[2]['name']) + "  " + str(text[2]['location']['addressLine']),
                                         callback_data="three")

    selectKeyboard.add(one,two,three)
```